# prove integral converge

Tags: integration, limits

Can you help me to figure out how to prove this:
$f(x)$ is continuous and bounded in $\mathbb{R}$, and  $\lim_{x \to \infty} e^{2x}f(x)=3$.
I need to prove that $\int_{0}^{\infty} f(\ln x)\,dx$ converges.
I think that $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x)=0$ but I don't see how to go from here.
I tried to use somehow the Dirichlet test and other converge tests but with no result. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose $f$ were defined as the function $f(x)=3e^{-2|x|}$, which is continuous and bounded everywhere, with $\lim_{x\to \infty}e^{2x}3e^{-2|x|}=3$.  Then, we see that $f(\log(x))=\frac{3}{x^2}$ and $\int_0^\infty \frac{3}{x^2}\,dx$ is divergent.

If we are only interested in the integral $\int_1^\infty f(\log(x))\,dx$, then note that for sufficiently large $x$, $2e^{-2x}\le f(x)\le 4e^{-2x}$.

Therefore, for sufficiently large $x$

$$\frac{2}{x^2}\le f(\log(x))\le \frac{4}{x^2}$$

and $\int_1^\infty f(\log(x))\,dx$ converges using the comparison test.

Comment: First of all thanks for the help. and if x approaches 0+?

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure.  There is a problem for $x$ near $0$.  We are not given anything regarding the behavior of $f(x)$ as $x\to -\infty$, which means we don't know $\lim_{x\to 0^+}f(\log(x))$.  For example, suppose that $f(x)=e^{-x}$ for $x\in[0,1]$.  Then, $f(\log(x))=e^{-\log(x)}=\frac1x$ and the integral diverges.

Comment: but f(x) could not be e^-x because f is bounded in R

Comment: Adam, $f(x)=e^{-x}$ for $x\in [0,1]$ is possible.  And we might even have $f(x)=3e^{-2|x|}$ for all $x$.  Then, $f$ is continuous and bounded with $e^{2x}f(x)\to 3$ as $x\to \infty$ and $f(\log(x))=\frac{3}{x^2}$ for $x>0$.